# Replace multiple lines in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using this script to replace a text in a file (Powershell V.1)

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'file.jnlp') -replace 'ruta_logo','logo/logo.png' 
| out-file 'file2.jnlp'"
```

But if I want to replace multiples lines how can I make the script? I was thinking something like this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc 'file.jnlp') -replace 'ruta_logo','logo/logo.png' 
-replace 'ruta_xsl','logo/xsl.xsl' `
-replace 'url_msg','url+msg'`
-replace 'url_forest','url+forest'`
-replace 'nombre_entidad','Nombre'`
-replace 'url_word','Word.exe' | out-file 'file2.jnlp'"
```

But is not working. So I'm using multiples batch files to replace a line. Thanks

Comment: You're missing a backtick at the end of the first line. Also, if you want to use PowerShell anyway, run the PowerShell code from a .ps1 file instead of passing it as a command string to `powershell.exe`. If that doesn't solve the problem you need to describe "not working" in more detail. Example input and both the expected and actual output are always helpful.

Comment: Also Out-File might present an encoding issue so you might need to use `-Encoding Ascii` for example. _But is not working_ does not help us determine your issue.

Comment: Are you seriously using PowerShell v1.0? That is what you see when you run `Get-Host`? Not even sure if `Get-Host` is available then.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks It worked prom powershell ISE. But if I want to run the shell as a .bat ... It's possible?

Comment: You can't wrap lines that way in a batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to post this Batch file solution for the following reasons:

- The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35637893/revisions) had the `batch-file` tag.
- The last OP's comment indicate that he wants to run the code from a .bat file.
- These points are *"interpreted by me"* as the best solution for this problem is to keep all the code in a single Batch .bat file.

.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < file.jnlp > file2.jnlp
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section

WScript.Stdout.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(
        /(ruta_logo)|(ruta_xsl)|(url_msg)|(url_forest)|(nombre_entidad)|(url_word)/g,
function (o,A,B,C,D,E,F)
{return ["logo/logo.png","logo/xsl.xsl","url+msg","url+forest","Nombre","Word.exe"]
        [[].concat(A,B,C,D,E,F).join().indexOf(o)] }));
```

As an additional benefit, this solution should run faster than the PowerShell one (and IMHO it is simpler also).